# NodeJS Queue multiple execFile calls

Tags: node.js, promise, child-process

I am making a web-based tool that hooks into an existing shell based framework called [RetroPie-Setup](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup).

They have a shell script called /RetroPie-Setup/retropie_packages.sh that you can use to install, grab dependencies, or even compile different programs.

One problem is packages.sh should not run multiple times at a given moment, so I need to setup a queue that runs one at a time.

I think I can use [promise-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue) to prevent multiple executions, but whenever I run execFile, it ends up running the command right away instead of when it hits a spot in the queue.

Here is my sample code:

**`downloadTest.sh`** (Downloads a 10Mb file with a unique name):

```
filename=test$(date +%H%M%S).db
wget -O ${filename} speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db
rm ${filename}
```

**Node Code**:

```
const Queue = require('promise-queue')
const { spawn,execFile } = require('child_process');
var maxConcurrent = 1;
var maxQueue = Infinity;
var que = new Queue(maxConcurrent, maxQueue);

var testFunct = function(file)
{
    var promise = new Promise((reject,resolve) => {
        execFile(file,function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('Finished executing');
            if(error)
            {
                reject();
            } else
            {
                resolve(stdout);
            }
        });
    })
    return promise;
}
var test1 = testFunct('/home/pi/downloadTest.sh')
var test2 = testFunct('/home/pi/downloadTest.sh')
var test3 = testFunct('/home/pi/downloadTest.sh')
que.add(test1);
que.add(test2);
que.add(test3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code were very close to working. The main problem is that you're executing `testFunct()`, which in turn returns a Promise that immediately starts executing what's inside it. To solve this, you can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the parameter to the function without executing it. Like this:

```
que.add(testFunct.bind(null, '/home/pi/downloadTest.sh'));
que.add(testFunct.bind(null, '/home/pi/downloadTest.sh'));
que.add(testFunct.bind(null, '/home/pi/downloadTest.sh'));
```

Alternatively you can use `async/await` which makes a queue trivial to implement, which in turn allows you to drop the dependency on `promise-queue`.

```
const execFile = require("util").promisify(require("child_process").execFile)

(async function () {
  let scripts = [
    "/home/pi/downloadTest.sh",
    "/home/pi/downloadTest.sh",
    "/home/pi/downloadTest.sh"
  ]

  for (let script of scripts) {
    try {
      let { stdout, stderr } = await execFile(script)
      console.log("successfully executed script:", script)
    } catch (e) {
      // An error occured attempting to execute the script
    }
  }
})()
```

The interesting part in the above code is `await execFile(script)`. When you `await` an expression, execution of the whole function is paused until the Promise returned by the `execFile` function either resolves or rejects, which means that you have a queue that is executed in sequential order.